# Using .net framework 4.6.1 on mac with m1

Tags: .net, macos, apple-m1

Good afternoon.
At work, we are developing an old project that uses such old things as .net framework 4.6.1, wcf, and so on. Now I'm working on a mac with intel, I'm running the project through visual studio in Parallels.

Wanted to know if I can work on a project on mac with m1?

Parallels released a virtual machine for m1, but it uses windows arm, as far as I read. Will it be possible to run such an old project on mac m1 via Parallels?

Comment: i'm trying to find a way to use .net 4.6.2 on a m1 pro, but with no luck. If i find a solution i'll report it as an answer

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried **.net 4.6** project in **Macbook Air M1** using **Parallel Desktop** and accessing **MMSQL database** through **Azure Data Studio** using **Docker**. It is working fine and i have create project and debugged it, everything works fine.

It has only 1 issue which still i am not able solved was CSS, *CSS and JS was not working when running project locally*. If anyone know the solution please share!

Comment: did you use visual studio in development?

Comment: Yes VS19, I am not understanding why it is not getting image assets, style when running locally!

Comment: I was able to test on a macbook with an m1 chip and my wcf app didn't start. Apparently, it all depends on the specific stack